# Как называется данный скрипт или библиотека для подсчета объектов?

Tags: map, framework

На сайте https://free.navalny.com/ имеется карта, на которой есть интересная функция: человек может сделать метку на карте, подтвердив её через e-mail. Как называется данный скрипт/фреймворк/библиотека?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду страницы, для отображения карты они пользуются библиотекой [leafletjs](https://leafletjs.com/). Отметки на карте при этом динамически грузятся из их бека:
[image: json-код ответа]